# How to read a 16-bit unsigned integer big endian binary file in Python

Tags: python, numpy, binaryfiles, endianness, rawimage

I need to read a 16-bit unsigned integer big endian binary file in Python. Here's some information that may be relevant:

- No. of Dimensions: 3
- Dimension Size: 64 x 384 x 384
- Max Dimension Size: 64 x 384 x 384
- Data type: 16-bit unsigned integer
- Storage Layout: CHUNKED 32 x 128 x 128
- Compression: 2.526:1 GZIP: level=2
- Storage: SIZE: 742159, allocation time: Incremental
- Fill value: NONE

The file itself is supposed to be a 3-dimensional image of a brain. I exported the file from an IMS file using HDFView. I want to convert the file to a numpy array. The file extension is ".bin".

#### Supplementary Information:

##### Picture of HDFView, a tool used to export the data in question from an IMS file

[HDFViewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQyJ5.png)

##### Link to a description of the IMS file-type

https://imaris.oxinst.com/support/imaris-file-format

##### Link to the machine used to make the IMS file

https://www.zeiss.com/microscopy/en/products/light-microscopes/light-sheet-microscopes/lightsheet-7.html

#### Data:

##### Google drive link to the data

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wo4iSBLvNu51qYPTyUpGdKgdwJUG0eed/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the name of the imaging device and a link to it. Also, if you could share a Dropbox or Google Drive link to the binary file that would help.

Comment: Okay, I'll do this

Comment: Mmmm... I know nothing about hdf5 stuff, so may be wrong, but ... the expected size of your file would be `64x384x384x2` bytes if uint16. The screen capture says it has been gzipped to 7472159 bytes at a ratio of 2.526 and the maths is correct. I'm now stuck because your file is not 747kB and it doesn't have the correct magic number at the start for `gzip`.

Comment: With `np.fromfile` you can read flat bin data with a dtype like '<u2' or '>u2'.  But that doesn't have an shape information.  I'm not familiar with what `HDFView` can export, so can't help with further details.  But with the `h5py` module it is possible to load data from `HDF5` files directly.

Comment: I used h5py and was able to export the data to a numpy array. Thank you @hpaulj !